# div fading in and out onClick doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I want to pop up a menu on click of a div and I got it all working in this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EhtrR/825/ but I cant manage to make it work on my code.

HTML:

```
<div id="clickOne" class="clickDesign">
<h2 class="fs20 nobold">Leafy Plants</h2>
</div>
<div  id="clickTwo" class="clickDesign">
<h2 class="fs20 nobold">Juicy Plants</h2>
</div>
</div>
<div id="leafyPlants">
Leafy Test
</div>
<div id="juicyPlants">
Juicy Test
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#leafyPlants{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
}

#juicyPlants{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
  $("#clickOne").on('click', function() {
   $("#leafyPlants").fadeIn();
   $("#juicyPlants").fadeOut();
});
$("#clickTwo").on('click', function() {
   $("#leafyPlants").fadeOut();
   $("#juicyPlants").fadeIn();
});
```

It doesn't show anything when I put it my code.

Comment: my bad wanted to edit ;\

Comment: add a jQuery library and put your script in a `$(function(){...here...})` doc ready block.

Comment: it works perfectly with your code.. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EhtrR/829/)

Comment: how to add one? I'm using wordpress btw

Comment: and i know it works in fiddle but not on my site..

Comment: Jai thanks that was all needed haha thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to work on your wordpress site, you'll have to include the jquery library.
Here is how:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
# Add this in your header.php in the <head> </head> section#
```